# How to find all initializations of instance variables in a Java package?

Tags: java, spring, refactoring, singleton, replace

I'm in the midst of converting a legacy app to Spring. As part of the transition, we're converting our service classes from an "instantiate new ones whenever you need one" style to a Springleton style, so I need a way to make sure they don't have any state.

I'm comfortable on the *nix command-line, and I have access to IntelliJ (this strikes me as a good fit for Structural Search and Replace, if I could figure out how to use it), and I could track down an Eclipse install, if that would help. I just want to make absolutely sure I've found all the possible problems.

**UPDATE**: Sorry for the confusion. I don't have a problem finding places where the old constructor was being called. What I'm looking for is a "bullet-proof" why to search all 100+ service classes for any sort of internal state. The most obvious one I could think of (and the only one I've really found so far) is cases where we use memoization in the classes, so they have instance variables that get initialized internally instead of via Spring. This means that when the same Springleton gets used for different requests, data can leak between them.
Thanks.

Comment: +1 for "Springleton" - it's going in my vocab now

Comment: Make the constructor `private` and watch the compile errors pop up in your IDE of choice.

Comment: +1 Or you can make it throw an exception, that would catch the scenario where an instance is created dynamically (E.g. Class.forName.neeInstance() )

Comment: @Shamit Though you are right, if any legacy code is creating instances of objects via reflection I would be worried :/

Comment: Its quite common if code was designed to be "extensible". E.g. if Adapter class for a data source can be specified in configuration XML or if an XML has list of services to be created.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse you can just right click on a variable/type and there is an option for References (or Declarations) -> (Workspace / Project / Hierarchy) which can help you find all instances of it neatly.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Eclipse's built in refactoring tool, it will do its best to change every instance associated to the class accordingly.  I would go a step further and rename the class of that you want to change so, at worst case, a full compile would fail and you can easily fix any of those issues.